# angular controllers works badly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-cli

I am new in angular, install angular / cli and I want to implement a controller to connect my application with sql serve but no driver is useful, nor the simplest

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div  ng-controller="myCtrl">
Full Name: {{firstName}}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpGfl.png)

Answer (score 0):

The above code is related to **`angularjs`** not **`angular`**.  There is not controller or scope with angular.

As soon you install the angular cli, run the command to generate the new project

**`ng new yourAppName`**

it will generate a new application named yourAppName, and do a npm start.

goto your app.component.ts file and add the following two variables,

```
firstName = "John";
lastName = "Doe";
```

and app.component.html,

```
<div>
Full Name: {{firstName}}
</div>
```

that's it.